# MVC3 Json model binding not working when sent to server

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a an odd problem with MVC3 and the model binding.
When I post a JSON object to my controller the model binder can't create a typed object out of it at all. All the properties are the default (i.e. empty strings)

However if I create an instance on the server, and send it as a JSON action result the data on the wire looks identical.

I've tried with

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

and it makes no difference

As an example if I post

```
{"RoutineName":"My new routine","Routines":[{"DayName":"Monday","Items":[21,31]}]}
```

The model binder fails, but coming from the server the data looks like

```
{"RoutineName":"Routine From Code","Routines":[{"DayName":"Monday","Items":[1,2]},{"DayName":"Tuesday","Items":[]}]}
```

The html used to generate this looks like

```
$('#submitRoutine').click(function () {
            var routines = [];
            $('.DayName').each(function (index, item) {
                var $item = $(item);
                var name = $item.html();
                var routineItems = [];
                $($item.attr('href')).find('.itemId').each(function () {
                    routineItems.push(parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
                });
                routines.push({
                    DayName: name,
                    Items: routineItems
                });
            });
            var routine = {
                RoutineName: $('#routineName').val(),
                Routines: routines
            };

            $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
            $.post('/Machine/CreateRoutine', JSON.stringify(routine),function (data) {},'json');
        });
```

So it looks like model binding from a typed object to JSON is ok, but coming back the other way isn't. Is there something I've missed?

The models are in F#

```
type RoutineDayViewModel() =
    let mutable _name = String.Empty
    let mutable _items = new ResizeArray<int>()

    member x.DayName with get() = _name and set value = _name <- value
    member x.Items with get() = _items and set value = _items <- value

type RoutineViewModel() =
    let mutable _name = String.Empty
    let mutable _routines = new ResizeArray<RoutineDayViewModel>()

    member x.RoutineName with get() = _name and set value = _name <- value
    member x.Routines with get() = _routines and set value = _routines <- value
```

EDIT:
I've also tried with the following C# classes and get the same result

```
 public class RoutineDayViewModel
    {
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public List<int> Items{ get; set; }
    }

    public class RoutineViewModel
    {
        public string RoutineName { get; set; }
        public List<RoutineDayViewModel> Routines { get; set; }
    }
```

I've also added the following to the global.asax

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory())
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your model look like?  You're using getters and setters right?

Comment: yeah they're F# models but have getters and setters just as a C# class would. I've added the model code to my question. ResizeArray is an F# name for List<T>

Comment: I know in C# you have to explicitly state that a controller allows JSON GET requests or else it will reject them.  Have you done that for your controllers? *My bad you're posting ><

Comment: Keep in mind that the model binder is going to look for properties with the same names as the objects you are accepting as part of the controller. In your controller action where you define that your action is accepting a RoutineViewModel, name it "model":  public ActionResult Sample(RoutineViewModel model)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the request content type to `application/json` if you intend to send a JSON formatted request which is what you are doing with the `JSON.stringify` method. So instead of:

```
$.post('/Machine/CreateRoutine', JSON.stringify(routine),function (data) {},'json');
```

you could use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Machine/CreateRoutine',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(routine),
    success: function (data) {

    } 
});
```

With this you don't need to set `$.ajaxSettings.traditional` nor you should be adding any `JsonValueProviderFactory` in your Global.asax as this provider is already added by default in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using Nick Riggs Postify javascript code

http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/